# Why query give not right results?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day.

Table have data:

```
id UserIdn CommentIdn LikeIdn NewsIdn Type IsFavorite DateCreate

1  527464             613895  748153  up   yes   0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

For get count values i use code:

```
SELECT 
count(Type='up') as CountUp, 
count(Type='down') as CountDown 
FROM Likes WHERE NewsIdn = '748153'
```

but in result instead

```
CountUp  CountDown
   1       0
```

i get

```
CountUp  CountDown
    1       1
```

Tell me please why i get not correct results? How query will be right?

Comment: Use COUNT instead of SUM,  sum summarizes,  count counts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a case when in a sum().

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'up' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'count_up'
...
```

Comment: Don't forget the END after ELSE 0.

Comment: now i get CountUp->NULL  CountDown->NULL. but need 0  instead `null`. how make it?

Comment: I've created a fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef5b/3

What data types are your columsn?

perhaps try your query without the WHERE condition?

Comment: in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1cde8/2  i get `1 0`, but in phpmyadmin i get `null null`, why different results??

Answer (score 1):

The `Type='up'` for example in your `COUNT()` function is either false (`0`) or true (`1`). But `COUNT()` doesn't care about that, it just sees that there is a row. Use `SUM()` instead:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(SUM(Type='up'), 0) as CountUp, 
COALESCE(SUM(Type='down'), 0) as CountDown 
FROM Likes WHERE NewsIdn = '748153'
```

Comment: now i get CountUp->NULL  CountDown->NULL. but need 0  instead `null`. how make it?

Comment: See my edit, coalesce() function returns first of its parameters which isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Type='up' AND Type IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountUp,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type='down' AND Type IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CountDown
FROM Likes
WHERE NewsIdn = '748153'
```

Comment: now i get CountUp->NULL  CountDown->NULL. but need 0  instead `null`. how make it?